# Solr Indexing for Sitecore

Tags: solr, sitecore

We have stored different language versions  content under each item in Sitecore and we need to create different Indexes for each language say if we have Italian and French versions version of Home page stored as a version then
we need different indexes for Different language version of Home page is there any setting which i Index Configuration file

Cheers
GA

Comment: Do you mean different language versions of items? Why do you want to create separate indexes for them? Just add your context language to the query and you'll receive only search hits in your chosen language.

Comment: Yes different different  versions of items since our content is huge for each language and for other reasons as well we need different Indexes for each language

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by creating a custom crawler, following is a sample code that configures the English language as the index language, I think you can start from there:

All the information can be found here:
https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/10/custom-sitecore-index-crawler.html

```
private string indexLanguage;

public string Language
{
  get  {  return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(indexLanguage) ? indexLanguage : null; }
  set  {  indexLanguage = value; }
}

protected override void DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
  using (new LanguageFallbackItemSwitcher(context.Index.EnableItemLanguageFallback))
  {
    Index.Locator.GetInstance<IEvent>().RaiseEvent("indexing:adding", context.Index.Name, indexable.UniqueId, indexable.AbsolutePath);
    if (!IsExcludedFromIndex(indexable, false))
    {
      foreach (var language in indexable.Item.Languages)
      {
        // only include English
        if (!language.Name.Equals(indexLanguage, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
          continue;
        }

        Item item;
        using (new WriteCachesDisabler())
        {
          item = indexable.Item.Database.GetItem(indexable.Item.ID, language, Version.Latest);
        }

        if (item == null)
        {
          CrawlingLog.Log.Warn(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SitecoreItemCrawler : AddItem : Could not build document data {0} - Latest version could not be found. Skipping.", indexable.Item.Uri));
        }
        else
        {
          SitecoreIndexableItem sitecoreIndexableItem;
          using (new WriteCachesDisabler())
          {
            // only latest version
            sitecoreIndexableItem = item.Versions.GetLatestVersion();
          }

          if (sitecoreIndexableItem != null)
          {
            IIndexableBuiltinFields indexableBuiltinFields = sitecoreIndexableItem;
            indexableBuiltinFields.IsLatestVersion = indexableBuiltinFields.Version == item.Version.Number;
            sitecoreIndexableItem.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter = context.Index.Configuration.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter;
            Operations.Add(sitecoreIndexableItem, context, index.Configuration);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    Index.Locator.GetInstance<IEvent>().RaiseEvent("indexing:added", context.Index.Name, indexable.UniqueId, indexable.AbsolutePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Update i am trying this but will this  customCrawler take care of Updating and deleting Indexing as well.

Comment: I created custom Sitecrawaler and specified same in Index configuration  this but could not get language specific index for example i could not get language specific Indexes . Any pointers